# Can I migrate EKS Fargate to EKS Node group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I am currently using EKS Fargate, but I would like to switch to Node groups and use it.

Therefore, Can I switch to the node groups instead of deleting the cluster?

Comment: It depends on how complicated your applications but I don't think we have a straight way to achieve that. For example, Fargate does not support EBS, but EKS has that; how to re-config environment variables (configmap, secret) ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can switch to node group easily. No need to delete the entire cluster.
You just need to create a Node Group with some node and then you can simply delete the Fargate Profile.
All the pod running on Fargate profile will be switched to available node on Node Group.

Additionally, You can always choose to use both Fargate profiles and node group . You can use Namespace name and/or combination of labels to make most use of it.

You can also create different Node group for different purpose using Labels. like,

Node Group1 - Kubernetes Labels (<key1>:<value1>) for purpose1

Node group2 - Kubernetes Labels (<key2>:<value2>) for purpose2

Make sure you are mentioning these labels in your Kubernetes yaml/yml or from your deployment file.

Yon can explore more on this from aws doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managed-node-groups.html